# I Want to make chart shows the Customer Deficiency and Surplus for Each Cashier in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

The customer is using Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations. The customer has asked me to create a report about his operations in his market using Power BI. he wants to see information about quantities, sales amounts, and all details related to invoices. One of his requirements is to view the performance of each cashier, including their sales, deficiencies, and surpluses. I am unsure about which tables and fields to use in order to create a chart that displays this information.

I have attempted to use tables such as
hcmworker, RetailStatementTable, RetailStatementTrans, and RetailTransactionSalesTrans.

From the RetailTransactionSalesTrans table, I was able to retrieve the quantity and sales amount, which are some of the details the customer wishes to see. However, the only challenge I am facing is how to present the deficiencies and surpluses for each cashier.

Comment: How are deficiencies and surpluses defined? Assume there is a "target" defined somewhere? And if so, what is the grain of the target? Per cashier, per day/month, per geo etc...

Comment: @SamNseir Per cashier, per day/month,

Comment: Yes, but where is this data stored? Is it in  D365 or separate data source?

Comment: @SamNseir yes, it is in the D365 but I do not know which table which field this is my question , I am new in D365 finance and operation I am trying to learn it